# airflow keep reading the default configuration for dags

Tags: python-2.7, airflow

I'm quite new with apache airflow, i changed the default configuration to read from new dag folder however when i start the scheduler it keep reading the dags from /home/airflow.
here is my configuration:

```
airflow_home = /home/airflow
dags_folder = /my_new_path/airflow_dags
```

etc. I kept the default configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Airflow reads the configurations form the airflow.cfg file. So make all your changes there. Also the path should be absolute.
Also you need to restart the web server after making all the changes:

- ctrl + c
- airflow webserver -p 8080

Comment: thanks. the problem was that .cfg file was duplicated